# MS Project (2013): How to assess impact of overtime?

Tags: ms-project, tasks, ms-project-2013

I have set up what I think is a relatively simple 2013 project using the default settings. I start with some manually scheduled milestones at the beginning followed by a bunch of auto-scheduled tasks. I have 5 people on a team, and each person can work any task so I set up one resource that maxes out at 500%.

I now need to see what the impact to the project end date would be if everyone worked 50 hours per week rather than the default 40. I go into Project Options - Schedule and change Hours per day and Hours per week to 10 and 50, respectively. The auto-scheduled task durations change as expected (i.e. a 5 day task reduces to 4 days), but the start and finish dates do not (they still represent the original 40hr/wk timeline). Also, after changing the default hours per day and week, if I go manually change the duration the start and finish dates no longer update like they did prior to changing the hours per day/wk. Any idea what happened and how I can get the desired result (which is to shorten the project length by working more hours)?

Comment: 25% overtime for the duration of a project will have a lot of implications (including everyone leaving the project). What is the actual purpose of this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get some help on a different thread but figured I'd post the solution here in case anyone else has the same questions I did: the baseline calendar updates I made as described only got applied to the tasks, not the resource. I had to create a custom 10hr/day calendar and apply that to the resource. Although it may not be the best or most elegant solution, it seems to have had the desired effect.

Comment: You may want to mark your answer as the correct one.